# Integrate an oracle Database View in my Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

i'm working with an existing oracle database with several database user. My problem is that i have to integrate an existing view in my Ruby on Rails Application, that is hold by another database user. My User has only 'granted' the rights for the view. How can I handle this?

Comment: What do you need to with it? Just view info from it? Treat it like an active record object etc.  assuming it doesn't match AR's default idea of what the table should look like.

Comment: Yes, I only want to view Info from it. What do you mean exactly? Is it sufficient when I generate a Model like 'rails generate model view_name' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help!

It was satisfactory, as @JimEvans solution, to create a Model:

```
  class TankBank < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "GEVIS.TANK_BANK"

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with the following:

Download basic, SQLPlus, SDK, instant client from Oracle website
(eg for Mac http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/intel-macsoft-096467.html)

Extract and move the above to /usr/lib
Create these symlinks:

```
ln -s libclntsh.dylib.12.1 libclntsh.dylib
ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so
```

Add this to your gemfile

```
  gem 'ruby-oci8'
  gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', :git => 'git://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced.git'
```

run `bundle install`

Run these commands:

```
export NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8"
export ORACLE_HOME=/bin/oracle/11_2x64
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
```

Now that you have this working, add an environment like:

```
my_oracle_db:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: IPADDRESS/INSTANCE
  username: USER
  password: PASSWORD
```

to your database.yml

Now create a model:

```
class OracleBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class=true
  establish_connection (:my_oracle_db)
  #whatever methods
end
```

And then create a model based off of your view in Oracle

```
class MyOracleView < OracleBase
  self.table_name = "SCHEMA.NAMEOFORACLEVIEW"
  #whatever methods you want to add
end
```

Then create your controller and view in Rails as usual. Also please note that you'll probably need to use all caps for the Oracle schema and table name.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a model to get data from the view.  Depending upon the view name and schema you might need to override AR's defaults.  For example say your view was called `other_user_view_ora` and had a primary_key called `user_id`, and you want to access it as `User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "user_id"
  set_table_name "other_user_view_ora"

  # database perms will enforce this, but just being pedantic
  def readonly?
   true   
  end
end
```

You should then be able to use the view like you would any ActiveRecord Object.

Another option would be to just issue sql commands via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`.  So in your controller do something like

```
def from_user_view
  @results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "select * from other_user_view_ora limit 2"
end
```

and then in your view you can iterate over the `@results` array, treating each result like a hash.

example:

```
<% @results.each do  |result| %> 
  <td><%=result['user_id']%></td>
  <td><%=result['name']%></td>
<% end %>
```